# How to initiate a click or link to change language in joomla 3

Tags: joomla-3.x, multilingual

I am having difficulty on using the language switcher in joomla 3.4.8 followed every step still not working.

I decided to create manual buttons each button will change to the language in question.

How can I create the link to change to french or English or any other loaded language?

I am looking for something programatically to load like this in module language switcher: `<a href="<?php echo $language->link;?>">`

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome the JSE. For other users please describe what steps you have already taken or give code examples of what you have already tried.

Answer (score 1):

The link has to be like:

www.yourweb.com/en   (for english)

www.yourweb.com/fr  (for french)

An so on.

But you have to have correctly configured your multilanguaje site for them to work.

Comment: thanks for the reply but that is obvious and static I am looking for something programatically to load like this in module language switcher.<code><a href="<?php echo $language->link;?>"></code>

Comment: Hi, then you have to elaborate more in the questions. In this place there are people of all level and profiles. Maybe it is obvious for you but not for someone else, and as I don´t know I just trying to help with the simplest answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

If the language switcher module doesn't work, it means that your multilingual configuration isn't right. So in this case you are going to have multilingual issues of any possible kind.

Asking to create manually the buttons is very similar to go and recreate the language switcher module, as otherwise what do you think this module is doing? So is this what you are trying to achieve? If so, just study the language switcher module and you will have your answer.